# Java swing background color fill outside the border

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border

I'm building a Java Swing app and I'm trying to achieve a backgroundcolor inside the border,

for some reason it spills outside the border as you can see here:

[image]

Fyi I need the TitleBorder to remain -> "TitledBorder.TOP" and not "BELOW_TOP"

Build with IntelliJ IDEA with Java SDK 8

Thank you for your time

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. We are NOT interested in the entire application, just a simple application that demonstrates the problem. So we would need your frame and a JPanel that demonstrates the improper background colouring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for some reason it spills outside the border

That is the way Swing painting works.

All Swing components have a parent / child relationship. So the top level component is painted, then the child is painted on top of the parent etc all the way down the parent/child tree. So each child overrides the background of its parent.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [A Closer Look at the Painting Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

1. So first the background of the panel is painted.
2. then the border is painted on top of the panel. In the case of a TitleBorder only the text and line is painted on top of the background.

If this is not acceptable to you then you would need to create a custom `Border` that would first:

1. paint the outer area of the Border in the same color as the background of the parent component.
2. Then draw the `TitleBorder`.

Or, maybe you could somehow do this by using a `CompoundBorder`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information.

Comment: Hello @camickr , Thank you for your reply. I have tryied with CompoundBorder but it didnt gave me the result I needed. I have also tried to create new Jpanel inside the Jpanel with the broder but  there is probably margin on Titleborder so it creates space between the border to the inside Jpanel

Comment: Well, I think I have a potential solution, but you still haven't posted your [mre], so I can't test it.